# scipy odeint, use of jacobin Dfun

Tags: odeint

I am trying to integrate a fairly large system.
As I create the system with sympy.physics.mechanics symbolically, it is easy to get the jacobian.
However, the speed to solve my differential equations only reduces marginally when I use Dfun in odeint.
Is this normal, or should giving Dfun make a large difference?

Thanks!